# How to use graphViz library in C++ program in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, graphviz

When I added: `#include < graphviz/cgraph.h>` in my C++ program ,I am getting this error message: fatal error: graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory.

By googling , I got the suggestion of adding file path of include file.

But I am not able to find the `graphviz/cgraph.h` location.

I have installed graphViz using :

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dperry/ppa-graphviz-test

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get autoremove graphviz

 sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
apt-get install graphviz-dev
```

Normally there are separate development versions of packages that include header files and other things you need to develop instead of just running applications.